# Use the Integrability Criterion to show that the function $f: I \to \Bbb R$ is integrable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

**Question:**

For the generalized rectangle $I= [0,1]\times [0,1]$ in the plane $\Bbb R^2$

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 5 & if\ \  (x,y)\ is\ in\ I\ and\ x> 1/2 \\ 1 & if\ (x,y)\ is\ in\ I\ \ and\ x\le 1/2 \end{cases}$$

Use the $\cal{Integrability\ Criterion}$ to show that the function $f: I \to \Bbb R$ is integrable.

---

$\cal{Integrability\ Criterion:}$

Bounded function $f: I \to \Bbb R$ is integrable $\iff$ for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a partition $P$ of $I$ such that $$U(f, P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$$

---

**Solution trial:**

Let $\epsilon >0$

For $k\in \Bbb N$, let $P_k$ be the partition of the interval $[0,1]$ of equal length $1/k$.

---

After then, how should I solve the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P_k$ be the partition of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ consisting of the following three parts: $\left[0,\dfrac12-\dfrac1k\right]\times\left[0,1\right],\left[\dfrac12-\dfrac1k,\dfrac12+\dfrac1k\right]\times\left[0,1\right],\left[\dfrac12+\dfrac1k,1\right]\times\left[0,1\right]$.

Then $U(f,P_k)=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac1k\right)\cdot1+\left(\dfrac{2}{k}\right)\cdot5+\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac1k\right)\cdot5$ and 
$L(f,P_k)=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac1k\right)\cdot1+\left(\dfrac{2}{k}\right)\cdot1+\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac1k\right)\cdot5$.

Therefore $U(f,P_k)-L(f,P_k)=\dfrac2k\cdot4=\dfrac8k\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}0$ and $f$ is integrable.

Comment: That's since $U(f, P)- L(f, P)=\frac{1}{4k^2}-\frac{1}{4k^2}=0<\epsilon$, $f$ is integrable. Right?

Comment: By the way, "or even $P=...$" is only an option. Is it?

Comment: @B11b: Yes is only an option. I think the better one!

Comment: Your second suggestion has a lot of appeal, but only if you fix the latter set to $(1/2,1]\times[0,1]$ me thinks. I do think that when studying Riemann-integrability it is customary to use the infima/suprema over closed intervals.

Comment: Dear @P.. $U(f,P)-L(f,P)=1/4k^2-1/4k^2=0 <\epsilon $ thus f is integrable and its integral is zero. Is it?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for that!!!

Comment: @B11b: My previous answer was wrong. I corrected it now. The integral is not zero. Is the limit of $U(f,P_k)$ (or $L(f,P_k)$) as $k$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Dear @P.. I have a question. How did you write $U(f,P_k)$ and $L(f,P_k)$ please can you explain ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the partition $P_\epsilon$ with only three parts:
$$
[0,\frac12-\frac\epsilon{20}]\times[0,1],\qquad [\frac12-\frac\epsilon{20},\frac12+\frac\epsilon{20}]\times[0,1]\quad\text{and}\quad [\frac12+\frac\epsilon{20},1]\times[0,1].
$$
In other words along the $x$-axes use split points at $1/2\pm\epsilon/20$, and along the $y$-direction you don't need any split points at all as the function does not depend on $y$.

Calculate the upper and lower sums related to these partitions, and see what comes out.